# Ubuntu package question

Tags: ubuntu, memcached, packages

I run Ubuntu, and If i type the following in a terminal, I start a new instance of memcached, right?

```
# memcached -vv
```

How can I target the the current instance of memcached in terminal?
It would help me to see the very-verbose mode on my already running instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `screen` command : it permits to put a terminal in background (Detached mode), where your application continue to work and reuse it later, from another machine if you want, to see the logs.

Think that verbose mode is time killing : your performance will be degraded.

Comment: Hi! I can understand that performance is degraded by verbose mode, but then again, it's only for development - not production. 

Should i use screen when I start up memcached or how do you mean?

Comment: you can run `screen` alone : it will start a new shell where you can start your command. Or You can run `screen memcached -vv` and it start the command immediately. To detach the terminal, the default sequence is Ctrl+A,D. You can list all screens launched by `screen -ls`, and recover by `screen -r PID` or without PID if just one is launched

Comment: Hi! Is there any way to get a current running instance of memcached into -vv mode by doing this?

Comment: What means "current running instance" ? You can have the name of the screen's session changed by -S option. Maybe this is what you want

Comment: I suspect the "current running instance" means "the daemon not started with -vv that I do not want to shut down flushing all my cache". Which would mean the answer simply would be "not possible".